# Javascript : Alert box only once when the user lands

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to display an alert box literally only once, i.e. when the user hits the website, then when they navigate through it does not appear any more?

Comment: Show the alert, create a cookie. Don't show the alert if cookie exists.

Comment: *"Is there a way to display an alert box literally only once, i.e. when the user hits the website, then when they navigate through it does not appear any more?"* Go ahead and alert on every page. Any reasonable visitor will only see the alert once because having gotten an alert upon reaching the page, they will navigate off the site entirely.

Comment: I use a layout, in which the code will reside. The user goes to different layouts in the site, if they go back to the main layout they will see the alert again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Commonly mobile websites feel an `alert` is the best way to advise they have a mobile app. That being said, I seem to revisit despite the alert (usually because google advises me to). Although I may just be glutton for punishment. ;-\

Comment: @MuhammedBhikha: You're missing my point. It's the 21st century, don't use `alert`. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could for example set a `localStorage` propertie like

```
if(!localStorage["alertdisplayed"]) {
    alert("Your text")
    localStorage["alertdisplayed"] = true
}
```

*Note that localStorage isn't supported by older Browsers, as noted by [blazemonger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901048/blazemonger) - [Compatibility List](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html#localstorage)*

An alternative would be setting a Cookie and check against its existence

If you don't know how to set / get cookies with javascript, i would suggest, reading this Article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie)

Comment: which would be great for the user as he isn't disturbed by an alert ;)
thx, i'll update the answer to point that out

Comment: This was a great answer until w3school was mentioned. ;-\ [mdn cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) is helpful as well.

Comment: Thx, why? Is there sth wrong with W3s , i just thought its maybe easier to understand for a beginner than mdn?  :)

Comment: @BradChristie Now i'm informed =) Thx, stumbled upon this link: http://w3fools.com/ on some of Pointys comments. Didn't ever knew that before

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the presence of a cookie, if not found, show the alert and set a cookie that expires after a very long time. Something like this:

```
if (!document.cookie.match(/(?:^|; *)alert_shown=1/)) {
    alert("Hello world");
    document.cookie = "alert_shown=1;max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
}
```

PS: I am not sure if the regex is bullet proof. And cookies could be... deleted.

Comment: +1 Finally a normal answer to his problem instead of just opinions about alerts

Answer (score 0):

You could drop a cookie with a very big expiry date the first time the user lands on the site. You can then check for the existence of that cookie and only display the alert box if it is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And you can use a cookie, local storage, database entry, or session variable (or a combination) to determine if they've already seen/waived the notice.

Chances are though that cookies or local storage are your only options given you're dealing with JavaScript. (Keep in mind though that local storage is still "new", not all browsers implement or support it yet).

side-note: You can also use AJAX and store the flag on the server (but this depends on your setup and what resources you have available).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an alert box, you should consider using a notification area. And then use cookies to prevent the notification are to show up more often then it should.